# App is crashing on adding @IBAction in view controller

Tags: ios, swift, toolbar, xcode9

I was trying to add a tool bar at the bottom of UITableView which is> successfully added. But when i connect the bar button with IBAction,
 on loading of that view controller app just crashes. Without linking
 to IbAction app works fine.

I am using xCode 9.2

Here is my storyboard.

[image]

[image]

Here is the crash log.

```
   2018-04-11 11:11:38.636121+0500 SafeBolt[9610:88848] *** Assertion failure in -[_UINavigationBarVisualProviderModernIOS _contentViewFittingHeight], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3698.33.6/_UINavigationBarVisualProviderModernIOS.m:569
    2018-04-11 11:11:38.662356+0500 SafeBolt[9610:88848] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Sigh. Contentview size is zero.'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001072b612b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001063fdf41 objc_exception_throw + 48
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001072bb2f2 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
        3   Foundation                          0x0000000105e9ed69 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 193
        4   UIKit                               0x00000001085d22f5 -[_UINavigationBarVisualProviderModernIOS _contentViewFittingHeight] + 265
        5   UIKit                               0x00000001083505e0 -[UINavigationItem _desiredHeightForBarMetrics:defaultHeightBlock:] + 90
        6   UIKit                               0x00000001085d4fa1 -[_UINavigationBarVisualProviderModernIOS heightRangeFittingWidth:] + 412
        7   UIKit                               0x0000000107ae40ed -[UINavigationBar _heightRangeForNavigationItem:fittingWidth:] + 210
        8   UIKit                               0x0000000107bc0a98 -[UINavigationController _intrinsicNavigationBarHeightRangeForViewController:] + 187
        9   UIKit                               0x0000000107bc09b6 -[UINavigationController _preferredHeightForHidingNavigationBarForViewController:] + 628
        10  UIKit                               0x0000000107bb088f -[UINavigationController _positionNavigationBarHidden:edge:initialOffset:] + 356
        11  UIKit                               0x0000000107bb0cf8 -[UINavigationController _positionNavigationBarHidden:edge:] + 388
        12  UIKit                               0x0000000107bb8555 -[UINavigationController loadView] + 243
        13  UIKit                               0x0000000107b7b05c -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 195
        14  UIKit                               0x0000000107b7b8b9 -[UIViewController view] + 27
        15  iOS_Slide_Menu                      0x00000001054bbe5a -[SlideNavigationController setEnableShadow:] + 74
        16  iOS_Slide_Menu                      0x00000001054b9804 -[SlideNavigationController setup] + 244
        17  iOS_Slide_Menu                      0x00000001054b9541 -[SlideNavigationController initWithCoder:] + 145
        18  UIKit                               0x0000000107e644c8 -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 246
        19  UIKit                               0x00000001080b9109 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 704
        20  UIKit                               0x00000001080b8e3e -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 89
        21  UIKit                               0x0000000107ae075a -[UINavigationBar initWithCoder:] + 753
        22  UIKit                               0x00000001080b9109 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 704
        23  UIKit                               0x00000001080b8e3e -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 89
        24  UIKit                               0x000000010834b5f2 -[UINavigationItem initWithCoder:] + 1018
        25  UIKit                               0x00000001080b9109 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 704
        26  UIKit                               0x00000001080b8e3e -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 89
        27  UIKit                               0x0000000107b76053 -[UIViewController initWithCoder:] + 432
        28  SafeBolt                            0x000000010448dfa2 _T08SafeBolt18BaseViewControllerCACSgSo7NSCoderC5coder_tcfc + 66
        29  SafeBolt                            0x000000010446db83 _T08SafeBolt26EmailListingViewControllerCACSgSo7NSCoderC5coder_tcfc + 1315
        30  SafeBolt                            0x000000010446dc4f _T08SafeBolt26EmailListingViewControllerCACSgSo7NSCoderC5coder_tcfcTo + 47
        31  UIKit                               0x0000000107e644c8 -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 246
        32  UIKit                               0x00000001080b9109 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 704
        33  UIKit                               0x00000001080b8e3e -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 89
        34  UIKit                               0x0000000107e64194 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 178
        35  UIKit                               0x0000000107e648d0 -[UIRuntimeEventConnection initWithCoder:] + 59
        36  UIKit                               0x00000001080b9109 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 704
        37  UIKit                               0x00000001080b92a7 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1118
        38  UIKit                               0x00000001080b8e3e -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 89
        39  UIKit                               0x0000000107e63391 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1262
        40  UIKit                               0x00000001082f3fc2 -[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:] + 181
        41  SafeBolt                            0x000000010448eda2 _T08SafeBolt11AppDelegateC23setUpRootViewControlleryyF + 386
        42  SafeBolt                            0x000000010448f6b5 _T08SafeBolt11AppDelegateC11applicationSbSo13UIApplicationC_s10DictionaryVySC0F16LaunchOptionsKeyVypGSg022didFinishLaunchingWithI0tF + 101
        43  SafeBolt                            0x000000010448f79a _T08SafeBolt11AppDelegateC11applicationSbSo13UIApplicationC_s10DictionaryVySC0F16LaunchOptionsKeyVypGSg022didFinishLaunchingWithI0tFTo + 186
        44  UIKit                               0x00000001079cabca -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 299
        45  UIKit                               0x00000001079cc648 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4113
        46  UIKit                               0x00000001079d1aeb -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1720
        47  UIKit                               0x0000000107d9b6f8 __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 924
        48  UIKit                               0x00000001081714c8 +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 153
        49  UIKit                               0x0000000107d9b2f1 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 249
        50  UIKit                               0x0000000107d9bb6b -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 696
        51  UIKit                               0x0000000108719a69 __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 262
        52  UIKit                               0x0000000108719922 -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 444
        53  UIKit                               0x00000001083f69c8 __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 221
        54  UIKit                               0x00000001085f5b06 _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 100
        55  UIKit                               0x00000001083f688b -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 231
        56  UIKit                               0x0000000108170b25 -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 392
        57  UIKit                               0x00000001079d036a -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 523
        58  UIKit                               0x0000000107fab605 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 369
        59  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010d340cc0 -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 338
        60  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010d3497b5 __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 235
        61  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010af5933d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
        62  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010af5e9f3 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 592
        63  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010d375498 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
        64  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010d37514e -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 464
        65  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010d3756bd -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
        66  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107259101 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
        67  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001072f8f71 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 81
        68  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010723da19 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 185
        69  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010723cfff __CFRunLoopRun + 1279
        70  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010723c889 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
        71  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010dcb79c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
        72  UIKit                               0x00000001079d35d6 UIApplicationMain + 159
        73  SafeBolt                            0x0000000104490d27 main + 55
        74  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010afd5d81 start + 1
    )
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
    (lldb)
```

Here is the code for IbAction.

```
@IBAction func testAction(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In which line does the crash occur ?

Comment: @Nitish Sorry actually i mean `Action/Outlet` whatever you are binding make sure it is properly binded in the VC.

Comment: @dahiya_boy : It is not mandatory to bind the outlet. If only action is to be used, property for outlet doesn't need to be created.

Comment: code would be helpful.

Comment: @Nitish probably connection is not proper that why app is crashing and there can not be any other issue (Most probably).

Comment: @dahiya_boy : Could be. Things would be much clearer if the OP shares the code.

Comment: @Nitish whenever i do the binding. App crashes.

Comment: @dahiya_boy I have added IbAction code as well. Joining this to button causing the crash

Comment: `reason: 'Sigh. Contentview size is zero.'
` Make sure the assertion doesn't fail.

Comment: Can you take new VC and do same and check whther it is working is your newVC or not?

Comment: Let me check that.

Comment: make sender to Any instead of UIBarButtonItem. i tested code i am not face crash issue
@IBAction func testAction(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Temp")
    }

Comment: @Hardik.T, Have you tried it with tableview ? Its only appearing when i am trying to add over a tableview. For simple view controller it works fine.

Comment: do you mean tableviewController ? or in view controller

Comment: In a view controller, add table view over view controller.

Comment: Is it possible there is some `UIBarButtonItem` with empty text? Note this is connected to the navigation bar, not the toolbar.

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following steps in order to solve this issue. Also let me know if it doesn't work for you.

> 1. Select the item in storyboard for which you are trying to add IBAction
> 2. Check in the connection inspector and see if there are still some extra connections other then the required one.
> 3. If there are other extra connections delete them and compile your code again. It should work.

This error usually happens when you create connections and deletes the code from your controller but your connection still exists.